# Exporting basemap tiles Contextily (ctx.bounds2raster) gives a black/empty GEOTIFF

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

When exporting a tile basemap (osm topo tile service) from Contextily using ctx.bounds2raster I get a black geotiff raster with no data in it. The properties of the raster say it's an 8 bit unsigned integer- which is surely not compatible with a 3 band raster representing the tile images.

The raster seems to be missing the CRS as well, but when I set the layer CRS to 3857, it projects to the correct place at least.

There is a CRS related error:

'PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db

-87658.19839440205 -65044.452373738226 7082306.226668285 7109249.279867188

Error  [line 29] The WKT could not be parsed. OGR Error code 6

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import geopy
import contextily as ctx
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, LineString
import pandas as pd
import sys, traceback

def excep():
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    errorM =  str(sys.exc_info()[1]).split("\n")[0]
    if "," in errorM:
        errorM = errorM.split(",")[0] + ". " + errorM.split(",")[1]
    lineN =  str(tbinfo).split(", ")[1]
    mess = "Error  [" + lineN + "] " + errorM
    print(mess)


def add_basemap(ax, zoom, source): 
    try:
        xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = ax.axis()
        print (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
        basemap, extent = ctx.bounds2img(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax,  ll=False, zoom=zoom, source=source)
        ax.imshow(basemap, extent=extent, interpolation='bilinear')
        basemap, ext = ctx.bounds2raster(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, r"C:\Temp\topo.tif",zoom=zoom)     
    except:
        excep()
        
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 5))

minx = 481062
maxx = 493021
miny = 405741
maxy = 420049
epsg = 27700

# Create a simple vector bounding box for my area and plot with geopandas
polyList = [(minx,miny),(minx,maxy),(maxx,maxy),(maxx,miny),(minx,miny)]
boundingbox_geom = Polygon(polyList)

area_df = pd.DataFrame(data= [['box',boundingbox_geom]],columns=['box','geometry'])
area_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(area_df,crs='epsg:{}'.format(epsg),geometry='geometry')

# get vector data into same CRS as tile services - Web Mercator
area_gdf2 = area_gdf.to_crs(epsg=3857)
area_gdf2.plot(ax=ax,alpha=0.5,color='yellow',lw=2,zorder=2,label='box')

topo = "https://a.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
add_basemap(ax, zoom=12,source=topo) 
plt.show()
```

It plots ok in web mercator (you can ignore the yellow box as that's just me adding some vector data using geopandas):

[image: plots successfully]

But the geotiff is black/empty (the black box matches the tiled basemap in the plot above):

[image: bad geotiff]

May be there are some syntax errors or I've misunderstood the contextily methods?

I would ideally like to request the tiles in EPSG:27700 so I can keep my plot in the CRS I want it in but wasn't sure how to do that, something like source_url&epsg=27700... but I will definitely need to export the image to a geotiff anyway for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on here. I have reproduced your code, which generates a .tif file I can open fine on QGIS, no black. I can also plot the file directly with rasterio:

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.plotting import show as rioshow
rioshow(rasterio.open("C:\\Temp\\topo.tif"))
```

And that plots the portion of the map (this is all on the latest 1.0.0 version and rasterio 1.1.5, which actually handles all the I/O).

More generally, contextily only currently works with tiles in Web Mercator (EPSG:3857). There is an issue here discussion potential extensions but these are at the idea level currently:

https://github.com/geopandas/contextily/issues/119

Note however that you can use the square trick you have above, together with ctx.add_basemap to retrieve the map, but this would be for display only, we currently have no functionality to query with a different CRS and write to disk in a GeoTif format. That would be a cool feature to have and should not be too hard to do (basically hook up the CRS option in add_basemap to the bounds2X methods), but it does not exist currently (PRs welcome!).

An alternative is to convert your 27700 coords into Web Mercator, use img2raster to write the Tiff in Web Mercator and then reproject either with QGIS, GDAL, or [rio transform](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html)

Answer (score 1):

A further update, although I can't be certain I have a hunch the problem related to the GDAL install.
Specifically the Windows Environment Variables: GDAL_DATA, GDAL_DRIVER_PATH, GDAL_VERSION.

Since I had multiple python environments, python 3.7x32, 3.7x64, 3.8x32 I therefore have multiple GDAL Env variables.  Perhaps when running a 3.7x64 script, the first GDAL variable it found in the registry was the 3.7x32 version pointing to the wrong GDAL resources- creating the error.

Trying to get contextily working involved installing GDAL windows msi installers on [www.gisinternals.com](http://www.gisinternals.com). Before using those I had a lot of visual studio errors CL.exe compiling errors when installing gdal via pip install. But after installing loads of versions from there I created more problems for myself.

SOLUTION:

1. I uninstalled all python environments
2. deleted all GDAL registry entries
3. deleted all python IDLE context menu registry entries
4. Installed GDAL 3.1.1 from a wheel from the [unofficial windows binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
5. Installed rasterio 1.15 from wheel
6. Fiona from wheel
7. pip install geopandas (as I need to combine with vector data too)
8. pip install contextily

and then contextily worked on 3.7x64!

My GDAL Env Variables look like this:
[image]

My Path Env Variables look like this:

[image]

And PYTHONPATH:

[image]